# Javascript: ForEach loop correct way to access json tag through this method

Tags: javascript, php, json, foreach

in order to get only a specific part of the php script i used a foreach with a condition relating to the id so it gave a scoped result. The issue i now have is how to access the information i have... ill show some examples to help illustrate my confusion

```
listCheck.innerHTML = "<img src = " + "./images/" + json[i].exhibits[j].exhibit_image + " Photo Cover' height='200' width='200'>";
```

After accessing the json this takes the appropriate data using the tag exhibit_image. However an adaption of this method using the ForEach leads to an error as i believe the code isnt aware of what im asking for which i believe to be a error in syntax

Here is the code i have tried...

```
function getNewYork()
{

myExhibitionsView = document.getElementById('exhibitioncontent');
images = document.createElement('ul');

    json.forEach( function(element) {
    if( element['exhibition_id'] == 1 ){
        console.log(element);
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < element[i].exhibits.length; j++) {
        list = document.createElement('p');
        list.id = 'image';
        list.innerHTML = "<img src = " + "./images/" + element[i].exhibits[j].exhibit_image + " Photo Cover' height='200' width='200'>";
        console.log(list);
        myExhibitionsView.appendChild(images);
        images.appendChild(list);

        }
        }




    };
});
}
```

i am trying to extract the exhibit image urls from this set of json

```
array("exhibition_id" => "1", "exhibition_title" => "New York, New York", "exhibition_subject" => "New York", "ticket_price" => "10",
        "exhibits" => array(
            array("exhibit_id" => "3", "exhibit_title" => "Brooklyn Bridge from City Hall Park", "exhibit_description" => "New York, June 2005", "exhibit_image" => "brooklynbridge.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
            array("exhibit_id" => "6", "exhibit_title" => "Central Park, New York", "exhibit_description" => "New York, June 2005", "exhibit_image" => "centralpark.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
            array("exhibit_id" => "7", "exhibit_title" => "Chrysler Building at night, New York", "exhibit_description" => "New York, July 2001", "exhibit_image" => "chrysler_building.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG")
        ),
        "locations" => array(
            array("location_id" => "1", "location_name" => "Kelvingrove Art Gallery and Museum", "location_postcode" => "G3 8AG"),
            array("location_id" => "3", "location_name" => "Walker Art Gallery", "location_postcode" => "L3 8EL"),
            array("location_id" => "5", "location_name" => "Tate Modern", "location_postcode" => "SE1 9TG")
        )
    ),
```

what is the correct syntax to do this? Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/kzzphmrp/

Looks like there were some issues with your code:

- You seem to use a string for the ID, but compared with a number in the javascript loop
- You have a superfluous loop, if you are doing foreach, you get the arrays *single elements* in your callback, so you do not need to loop over the whole array again (like you did here: `for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) { ... }`) Just remove this loop and loop over the elements "exhibits" property: `for (var j = 0; j < element.exhibits.length; j++)`
- Corrected some Problems with your HTML output, I think you forgot "alt" there

I this what you want to achieve?